# Oracle Query based on data to horizontal

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I want to query these below data sample. (Oracle database)

table name: FL_TEST

```
NAMA    JAM  STATUS
A       2    P
A       1    O
A       3    O
B       1    O
B       2    P
B       3    O
C       1    O
C       2    P
C       3    P
```

to be like this:

```
NAMA    JAM1 JAM2 JAM3
A       O    P    O
B       O    P    O
C       O    P    P
```

Is it possible to do that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use conditional aggregaiton

```
select NAMA ,max(case when jam=1 then status end) as jam1,
max(case when jam=2 then status end) as jam2,
max(case when jam=3 then status end) as jam3
from FL_TEST group by NAMA
```

or  you can use pivot

```
SELECT *
  FROM FL_TEST
PIVOT (
  MAX(status) as JAM FOR jam IN (1,2,3)
 );
```

Comment: How about JAM1, JAM2, JAM3 is auto from data?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave that would require dynamic SQL

Comment: Is it possible? We can't handle JAM manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Conditional Aggregation` :

```
select nama, 
       max( case when jam = 1 then status end ) as jam1,
       max( case when jam = 2 then status end ) as jam2,
       max( case when jam = 3 then status end ) as jam3
  from tab
 group by nama
```

or `pivot`  :

```
select * 
  from tab
 pivot(
       max(value) for field in ( 1 as "Jam1", 
                                 2 as "Jam2",
                                 3 as "Jam3" ) )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e1be5ae701148046c4e466f62733130c)</kbd>

Comment: How about JAM1, JAM2, JAM3 is auto from data?

Comment: dynamical case is not possible by only using Oracle's sql @HiDayurieDave

Comment: Is that mean we need to use another table or do on programming?

Comment: it could be figured out by dynamic SQL, or by using some array methods within PLSQL @HiDayurieDave

Comment: thank you bro for the edit @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin